# How to customly reorder tick values on x-axis in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to create a line plot where x-axis tick labels start from 12:00 to 00:00 and ends at 11:59. My data sorted so that TIME starts from 12:00 and ends at 11:59. This is the plot I end up: [image]

I am not sure why the straight line, and the line on the left axis of line plot pops up. How can I solve this issue? I expect to see the line plot, x-axis represents TIME column and starts from 12:00, and ends at 11:59. The line should be nice.

To solve thiss issue, I changed the xAxis domain to `.domain([parseTime("12:00:00"), parseTime("23:59:00")])` But that weird straight line and lefgt line of theplot pops. up. I appreciate any hints.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 CSV Example</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* LINE CHART */
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ed3700;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>D3 CSV Example</h1>
  <script>
    // Set up the SVG container
    const svgWidth = 600;
    const svgHeight = 400;
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 };
    const chartWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    const chartHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const svg = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", svgWidth)
      .attr("height", svgHeight);

    const chart = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    // Load the data from CSV
    d3.csv("reordered_synthetic_data.csv").then(function (data) {
      // Parse the date string and extract only the time as hours and minutes
      const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");

      // Convert data types
      data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.TIME = parseTime(d.TIME);
        d.VALUE1 = +d.VALUE1;
        d.INSPECTION = +d.INSPECTION;
      });

     let visit1 = data.filter(d => d.INSPECTION == 1);


// Set up scales
const xScale = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain([parseTime("12:00:00"), parseTime("23:59:00")]) // Set the domain manually
  .range([0, chartWidth]);

const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 180])
  .range([chartHeight, 0]);

      // Set up axes
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M")); // Format the tick labels to display hour:minute

      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

      // Add axes to the chart
      chart
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${chartHeight})`)
        .call(xAxis);

      chart.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis").call(yAxis);

      // Define the line function
      const line = d3
        .line()
        .x((d) => xScale(d.TIME))
        .y((d) => yScale(d.VALUE1));


      // Draw the line chart
      chart
        .append("path")
        .datum(visit1)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
    });


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find my CSV file:

```
DATE_TIME,ID,HOUR,MINUTE,VALUE1,VALUE2,TIME,INSPECTION,seconds
2018-11-01 12:00:00,1,12,0,82.4818356370727,87.65532538616083,12:00:00,1,720
2018-11-01 12:20:00,1,12,20,114.36084687826856,89.76606638044296,12:20:00,1,740
2018-11-01 12:40:00,1,12,40,149.2745234585085,78.59914264907545,12:40:00,1,760
2018-11-01 13:00:00,1,13,0,118.46198153923852,71.602023294704,13:00:00,1,780
2018-11-01 13:20:00,1,13,20,113.47363946789812,82.9802315554754,13:20:00,1,800
2018-11-01 13:40:00,1,13,40,124.52765200932272,79.25241460867473,13:40:00,1,820
2018-11-01 14:00:00,1,14,0,144.94079558959947,65.9708531211893,14:00:00,1,840
2018-11-01 14:20:00,1,14,20,154.4860403982185,62.47993589006475,14:20:00,1,860
2018-11-01 14:40:00,1,14,40,103.05095426442168,79.12278561261758,14:40:00,1,880
2018-11-01 15:00:00,1,15,0,88.71000005665377,72.63269391153845,15:00:00,1,900
2018-11-01 15:20:00,1,15,20,118.38725463585833,68.35955256035255,15:20:00,1,920
2018-11-01 15:40:00,1,15,40,90.35575706090954,84.996720275759,15:40:00,1,940
2018-11-01 16:00:00,1,16,0,119.53679642856682,64.48688419793011,16:00:00,1,960
2018-11-01 16:20:00,1,16,20,135.27829999848916,74.48257447199506,16:20:00,1,980
2018-11-01 16:40:00,1,16,40,155.48291761113225,83.72128851838752,16:40:00,1,1000
2018-11-01 17:00:00,1,17,0,85.96341780030743,87.73333389566491,17:00:00,1,1020
2018-11-01 17:20:00,1,17,20,148.20928658532694,68.51872403107251,17:20:00,1,1040
2018-11-01 17:40:00,1,17,40,112.90401161612893,78.71422067548829,17:40:00,1,1060
2018-11-01 18:00:00,1,18,0,87.24314271333824,85.14578512967933,18:00:00,1,1080
2018-11-01 18:20:00,1,18,20,159.98777892013288,73.91122953488058,18:20:00,1,1100
2018-11-01 18:40:00,1,18,40,134.132508027465,62.87714757838526,18:40:00,1,1120
2018-11-01 19:00:00,1,19,0,93.8475785922444,85.87709920539899,19:00:00,1,1140
2018-11-01 19:20:00,1,19,20,87.96494807670916,64.32810207816041,19:20:00,1,1160
2018-11-01 19:40:00,1,19,40,96.85350185792925,87.67564666896372,19:40:00,1,1180
2018-11-01 20:00:00,1,20,0,150.49329018102594,75.28292350135503,20:00:00,1,1200
2018-11-01 20:20:00,1,20,20,132.90939839406852,67.6641419034086,20:20:00,1,1220
2018-11-01 20:40:00,1,20,40,80.28565707426297,54.21677488141204,20:40:00,1,1240
2018-11-01 21:00:00,1,21,0,86.51819145398362,76.47547776446376,21:00:00,1,1260
2018-11-01 21:20:00,1,21,20,100.58643623741963,54.02216986378453,21:20:00,1,1280
2018-11-01 21:40:00,1,21,40,109.88077988150214,88.83099789311015,21:40:00,1,1300
2018-11-01 22:00:00,1,22,0,133.64148337171653,86.82795237554191,22:00:00,1,1320
2018-11-01 22:20:00,1,22,20,141.1790901060669,55.91956277329068,22:20:00,1,1340
2018-11-01 22:40:00,1,22,40,106.49414930906852,74.54271614590431,22:40:00,1,1360
2018-11-01 23:00:00,1,23,0,140.44553457410672,78.3447955131424,23:00:00,1,1380
2018-11-01 23:20:00,1,23,20,102.26703222395386,54.51054689408265,23:20:00,1,1400
2018-11-01 23:40:00,1,23,40,138.07031707200693,80.52691368274375,23:40:00,1,1420
2018-11-01 00:00:00,1,0,0,131.8403388480975,163.40706930229612,00:00:00,1,0
2018-11-01 00:20:00,1,0,20,128.66143180880016,182.4166850946821,00:20:00,1,20
2018-11-01 00:40:00,1,0,40,157.9838672230082,177.12826879097582,00:40:00,1,40
2018-11-01 01:00:00,1,1,0,154.74491894762372,177.0205615343229,01:00:00,1,60
2018-11-01 01:20:00,1,1,20,145.17425322202857,170.28572211898427,01:20:00,1,80
2018-11-01 01:40:00,1,1,40,86.33692934233684,161.306233500133,01:40:00,1,100
2018-11-01 02:00:00,1,2,0,157.70472270832147,175.57007397898963,02:00:00,1,120
2018-11-01 02:20:00,1,2,20,92.04378773072384,152.75885569609832,02:20:00,1,140
2018-11-01 02:40:00,1,2,40,94.91482763887927,164.34713115356462,02:40:00,1,160
2018-11-01 03:00:00,1,3,0,150.58752716935703,152.5739950034875,03:00:00,1,180
2018-11-01 03:20:00,1,3,20,147.64763286003245,181.7346317353725,03:20:00,1,200
2018-11-01 03:40:00,1,3,40,152.00311766772614,169.43438782829136,03:40:00,1,220
2018-11-01 04:00:00,1,4,0,90.67568616871652,165.94364405219295,04:00:00,1,240
2018-11-01 04:20:00,1,4,20,127.6260776280666,154.41327889693227,04:20:00,1,260
2018-11-01 04:40:00,1,4,40,88.35193693321801,86.7514997924824,04:40:00,1,280
2018-11-01 05:00:00,1,5,0,99.44723697225662,61.81705113015809,05:00:00,1,300
2018-11-01 05:20:00,1,5,20,153.28490595395064,70.71671056760238,05:20:00,1,320
2018-11-01 05:40:00,1,5,40,139.53124376248127,86.96902617467873,05:40:00,1,340
2018-11-01 06:00:00,1,6,0,144.5960580946409,53.46091762212306,06:00:00,1,360
2018-11-01 06:20:00,1,6,20,110.0561197803852,73.32550566412914,06:20:00,1,380
2018-11-01 06:40:00,1,6,40,151.21482961729612,50.85883825605632,06:40:00,1,400
2018-11-01 07:00:00,1,7,0,127.88766918064591,52.45266678876003,07:00:00,1,420
2018-11-01 07:20:00,1,7,20,148.72830141013,60.496196118302194,07:20:00,1,440
2018-11-01 07:40:00,1,7,40,83.62908148257569,86.54612924908034,07:40:00,1,460
2018-11-01 08:00:00,1,8,0,113.49475177931872,59.15439348393694,08:00:00,1,480
2018-11-01 08:20:00,1,8,20,139.37377082538475,86.1347823168292,08:20:00,1,500
2018-11-01 08:40:00,1,8,40,104.5216263376223,86.92624219265554,08:40:00,1,520
2018-11-01 09:00:00,1,9,0,152.55680056900144,60.938994790632144,09:00:00,1,540
2018-11-01 09:20:00,1,9,20,140.38896796205978,56.19504976107255,09:20:00,1,560
2018-11-01 09:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996857,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
2018-11-01 10:00:00,1,10,0,139.82904911416367,55.70678841865249,10:00:00,1,600
2018-11-01 10:20:00,1,10,20,91.69787531743796,60.136426910820354,10:20:00,1,620
2018-11-01 10:40:00,1,10,40,96.81085932421924,80.24824051838286,10:40:00,1,640
2018-11-01 11:00:00,1,11,0,100.11254271252508,60.56291710797137,11:00:00,1,660
2018-11-01 11:20:00,1,11,20,92.56760281588778,71.09234847495347,11:20:00,1,680
2018-11-01 11:40:00,1,11,40,100.3186503333999,72.55516506446128,11:40:00,1,700
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question...

The horizontal line appear because your data is not ordered by dates and you have dates that are "sooner" at the end of your dataset. `d3.line` iterate through data in the order of the array you provide.

You can sort your data before plotting it by using

```
data.sort((a,b)=>a.TIME-b.TIME);
```

if you want to plot all your data you can compute min and max date for your x scale like so:

```
        const justDate = data.map(d=>d.TIME);
        // Set up scales
        const xScale = d3
            .scaleTime()
            .domain([Math.min(...justDate), Math.max(...justDate)]) // Set the domain manually
            .range([0, chartWidth]);
        data.sort((a,b)=>a.TIME-b.TIME);
```